# Getting a direction from rotation around the Z

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, math

I have a plane. It is rotated 180 degrees on the Y , his position is 0,0,0 he is facing the X axis. That means that I rotate it around the Z (Euler angles) to change the direction it is facing. I have clouds the clouds have a movement script. I want the clouds to move in the opposite direction of the direction the plane is facing at the Y axis and X axis.

For example when the plane's rotation.eulerAngles.Z = 0. The clouds should move at full speed toward minus X. And when rotation.eulerAngles.Z = 90 the clouds should move at full speed towards minus Y. When rotation.eulerAngles.Z = 45 the clouds should move at half speed towards minus X and at half speed towards minus Y and so on.

Here's two illustrations to make it easier for you to visualize :

[illustration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivXCc.jpg)
[illustration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDD6x.png)

Here's a photo of the scene again to make it easier for you to visualize:

[the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvi5X.png)

The idea is to create the illusion that the plane is moving, actually moving the plane in this scene will make a lot of problems that I really don't want to deal with.

Current cloud movement script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCloud : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed;
    void Update()
    {
        var plane = GameObject.Find("plane");
        var dir =(plane.transform.position - plane.transform.forward)*speed*Time.deltaTime ;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + dir.x , transform.position.y + dir.y , transform.position.z);
        if (transform.position.x < -140)Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

So how would you approch this problem ?

With unity.

Edit:
I think trigo may be helpful here using a linear function
here's my new code :

```
   public float speed;
    void Update()
    {

        var plane = GameObject.Find("plane");//Get the airplane
        var slope = Mathf.Tan(360 - plane.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);//Degrees to a slope (how much y it does in one x)
        var y = 1*slope;//kinda the very definition of the slope...
        var x = 1/slope;//math
        transform.position += new Vector3(x,y,0)*Time.deltaTime*speed;//the 1 , 1 point of our linear function(our direction) * delta * speed

        if (transform.position.x < -140)Destroy(gameObject);
    }
```

currently the clouds just shake all over the scene. sometimes they do finally go to the right direction but it's not idle.
Would like to get a second opnion on my math.

How I solved the problem :
I just did

```
 transform.position += GameObject.Find("plane").transform.right * Time.deltaTime * speed;
```

Thanks to PrinceOfRavens for his help on finding this out

Comment: does the blue axis(x) of the airplane face forward?

Comment: z axis not x. my bad

Comment: I took me some time to realize that by "plane" you mean an airplane and not a geometrical (2D) plane. Nice plane by the way!

Comment: Oh sorry didn't think about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does the blue axis(z) of the airplane face forward? with the code you have implemented? what direction do the clouds move?

forward in unity is the red axis (z). you code should work if the plain is oriented correctly. find the axis thats coming from the nose, and note the color. 
if its :
 blue you want  `-transform.right`,
 green you want `-transform.up`

Comment: well the red axis is the X and yes my +x is my forward direction

Comment: plus x will b your forward because its camera x. screen space not world space. if you rotated your object 180 on the y, forward is backwards, and vice versa.   try `+ plane.transform.forward)`

Comment: with your code as it is,  which way do the clouds move?

Comment: because your forward is reversed(180 on y) so you should just make the clouds move in the planes forward direction, that should make them 'move past you' to the back of the plane

Comment: they rapidly move towards -x no matter what direction the plane is looking towards

Comment: you were close so ill give you the green v , anyway solution in edit.